# How to cater for single quote in pre_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have the below preg_match_all function. I need to add support for a single quote. I tried `'` but it did not work. Also, I tried escaping the single quote with a backslash this way `\'` but the forward slash gets stripped.

Example string `This - is Mary's phone`

```
preg_match_all('@[A-z0-9 ./áàâäãåǻăāąấấặắǎȧạàãáćĉċčççďđḑḋḍdéèêëĕěēęėềẽȩẹéĝğġģǧǵḡĥħȟḣḥḩíìîïĭїĩīįǐĪỊ̣iỊǏĨị̣ịıíĵ
ķǩḱḳļľŀĺĺóòôöõðőŏōỏǒǫȯoøồớòóõöñńņňŉŋǹṅṇŕŗřṙṛśŝşšṡṣşșţťŧțṫṭtúùûüůūűųũŭǔǘǚǜụuưüúŵ
ŷýÿўỹẏỳỵyẙȳẙźżžẑẓḅḟḿṁṃṕṗṽṿḷẁẃẅẉẘẘẋẍÒÓÔÕÖŐǑǪŌȮØÙÚÛǓǗǙǛŨŮŰŲÜỤŪĆĈČÇÀÁÂÃÄÅẠĄĀȦǍ
ÈÉÊËĖĘĚẸẼĒȨḾṀṂŚŜŞŠṠṢŹŻŽẐẒŃŅŇṄṆÑǸḢḤḨĤȞĹĻĽĿŢŤṪṬŖŘṘṚĜĠĢǦǴḠẀẂẄẈŴḊḌḐĎĐÐṔṖĶǨḰḲẊẌ
ṼṾỴỸỲẎŸȲŶÝĴȷḄḞḶŁłÏÎÍÌıİßıs-]+#[^#]+@', $matches, $countries);
```

Comment: May I ask _why are you using all this RegEx?_ Are you trying to match strings that contains `'` ? It would be easier if you provide an example input and the expected output.

Comment: The string is alphanumeric, contains hyphens, spaces, accented characters and the single quote which I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Check out this example string I'm working with.```Example - Êxámplĕ - Mary'š 1960 phone.```

Comment: Just add `\'` in there.  Or use `"` to surround the pattern then just use `'` in the pattern.

Comment: Second option worked!

Comment: `[A-z]` isn't what you think (a shortcut for `[A-Za-z]`), it's a range between A and z in the ASCII table that also includes `[ ] \ \` _ ^` (see the ASCII table).

Comment: When you use unicode characters (characters beyond the ASCII range that are encoded with several bytes in utf-8) in your pattern or in your subject string, put the `u` modifier after the second pattern delimiter. You can also use the `i` modifier to make your pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: To finish, instead of writing one by one all accented characters, read the unicode table and use ranges, or if it fit your requirements, use the [`\p{Latin}`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) character class (with eventually `\p{M}` that contains combining characters).